# Find a regular expression for the following language

Tags: formal-languages, regular-expressions

I was given an example in class. It goes as follows:

Let the alphabet be $\{a, b\}$.
$L$ is the string with one $b$ and at least two $a$'s
Find a regular expression that generates this language.

This was my professor's answer: $r = aaa^*ba^*+abaa^*+baaa^*$

My question with this solution is:

Wouldn't this regular expression FORCE $aa$, $aba$, and $baa$ to be together, respectively? Like, there doesn't seem to be a constraint that $a$ must follow $a$ in the first term, or that $a$ must precede $b$ which must precede $a$ in the second, etc.

That's why this was my answer: $r = a^*aa^*aa^*ba^* + a^*aa^*ba^*aa^* + a^*ba^*aa^*aa^*$

It still forces there to be one $a$ and at least two $a$'s, but it doesn't make them be right next to each other.

Which solution is correct?
I hope I explained myself correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both answers are correct.

First note that the following regular expression works:

$$a^*aaba^*+a^*abaa^*+a^*baaa^*\;.$$

The first term catches every word of $L$ that has a pair of $a$s anywhere after the $b$, the second catches every word that has the $b$ between two $a$s, and the third catches every word that has two $a$s anywhere after the $b$. Of course, many words are caught by more than one term, but that’s perfectly all right. It doesn’t matter that I specify that the two $a$s are together: in any string of two or more $a$s, there are two that are adjacent, and I can always choose them to be the first two or the last two.

Your answer is simply an inefficient version of this one. Your $a^*aa^*aa^*ba^*$ is exactly equivalent to $a^*aaba^*$, both generating every string that has at least two $a$s before the $b$. Similarly, your $a^*aa^*ba^*aa^*$ is equivalent to $a^*abaa^*$, both generating every string that has at least one $a$ on each side of the $b$. And your third term is similarly equivalent to mine.

This can be simplified if we observe that either the $b$ comes first, in which case we must have $baaa^*$, or it comes last, in which case we must have $a^*aab$, or it comes between two $a$s, in which case we must have $a^*abaa^*$. Thus, the expression

$$baaa^*+a^*abaa^*+a^*aab$$

will work just fine.

Your professor simplified it a little differently. First, $aaa^*ba^*$ catches every word of $L$ that has at least two $a$s before the $b$. If a word of $L$ does not have two $a$s before the $b$, then either it starts $aba$, in which case it’s caught by $abaa^*$, or it starts $baa$, in which case it’s caught by $baaa^*$.

Comment: Sorry, I think the formatting of the answer caused her original answer to not show all the * and instead italicized the b. Is her answer that you see now also incorrect? @Brian M. Scott

Comment: @FrostyStraw: Okay, give me a few minutes to rewrite my answer.

Comment: Both his and the prof's answers are correct; if you leave the $a^*$ on both sides of the first and third terms, you can get rid of the $a^*$ from the second term.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $a^*aa^*$ is equivalent to $aa^*$. Using that, your expressions reduce to:

$$r = aaa^*ba^* + aa^*baa^* + a^*baaa^*$$

This expression does generate that language. But it can be reduced further.
Note that `aaba` would match both the first and second terms of the expression. In fact, you can reduce the expression to just this:

$$r = aaa^*ba^* + aba + a^*baaa^*$$

Your prof's expression was:

$$r = aaa^*ba^* + abaa^* + a^*baaa^*$$

which can likewise be reduced to

$$r = aaa^*ba^* + aba + a^*baaa^*$$

Answer (score 1):

Since the alphabet is so small we can enumerate all possibilities the only thing which could be close to b is a, and there must be at least 2 of them. Those number of permutations of 2 among 3: $\frac{3!}{2!} = 3$ : aab,aba,baa, then we need to fill out the rest with potential a's to both left and right.

So yet another expression would be $a^*((aab) + (aba) + (baa))a^*$